# Non-linear property interpolation for interactive transitions

Tags: ios7, core-animation

In the implementation of an interactive transition, I'd like to mimic the animated transition that uses the non-linear easing functions. After searching around CA, it looks like interpolation machinery is all hidden behind private APIs.

- Is there a way to leverage Core Animation to do the grunt work for me?
- Do I need to roll my own value interpolation?
- Is there some existing open source lib that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that instead of manually modifying all the properties myself, I can schedule the animation normally, then set the layer `speed` to `0` and control the progress using the layer's `timeOffset` property. Given the animation duration is 1 second, the `percentComplete` maps directly to the `timeOffset`.

I've learned this from the [iOS Core Animation: Advanced Techniques](http://books.google.com/books?id=QfhdAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT191&dq=&hl=de&pg=PT191#v=onepage&q=&f=false) by Nick Lockwood.

Comment: If this solved your problem, you are [encouraged to accept your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).